# Twitter like following in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I'm following along with this [tutorial to create Twitter like following](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users) in my app, however, my following isn't reciprocal, in fact, the other side doesn't follow a user at all.  My two main models are `User` and `Stock`.  A user should be able to 'follow' a stock, but a stock does not ever follow a user.

> models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :stock_relationships
  has_many :stocks, through: :stock_relationships, source: :user

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :google_oauth2]

   # stock following/unfollowing
   def follow_stock(stock)
     stock_relationships.create(stock_id: stock.id)
   end

   def unfollow_stock(stock)
     stock_relationships.find_by(stock_id: stock.id).destroy
   end

   def following_stock?(stock)
     stock_relationships.include?(stock.id)
   end

end
```

Since my `Stock` model doesn't really belong to anyone I don't have anything in that model yet:

> models/stock.rb

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

To keep track of the `users` that are `following` stocks, I've created another model called `StockRelationships`:

> models/stock_relationship.rb

```
class StockRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm starting off in console by assigning a user:

```
user = User.find(1)
```

I'm having trouble because this doesn't seem to be working when using the `following_stock?` method.

I can create a `stock_relationship`:

```
pry(main)> user.follow_stock(stock)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "stock_relationships" ("stock_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["stock_id", 2], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-07-12 01:01:00.552580"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-12 01:01:00.552580"]]
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<StockRelationship:0x007ff0b960ba60
 id: 3,
 user_id: 1,
 stock_id: 2,
 created_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 01:01:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 01:01:00 UTC +00:00>
```

and I can `unfollow` a stock:

```
[10] pry(main)> user.unfollow_stock(stock)
  StockRelationship Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "stock_relationships".* FROM "stock_relationships" WHERE "stock_relationships"."user_id" = $1 AND "stock_relationships"."stock_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["stock_id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "stock_relationships" WHERE "stock_relationships"."id" = $1  [["id", 3]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<StockRelationship:0x007ff0b9d36a60
 id: 3,
 user_id: 1,
 stock_id: 2,
 created_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 01:01:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 01:01:00 UTC +00:00>
```

However, I'm running into problems when I'm checking to see if a user is actually `following` a stock:

```
[13] pry(main)> user.following_stock?(stock)
=> false
```

Which should be returning `true` since the user is in fact following the stock:

```
[15] pry(main)> StockRelationship.all
  StockRelationship Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "stock_relationships".* FROM "stock_relationships"
=> [#<StockRelationship:0x007ff0bfa00408
  id: 2,
  user_id: 1,
  stock_id: 1,
  created_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 00:32:55 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 00:32:55 UTC +00:00>,
 #<StockRelationship:0x007ff0bfa002c8
  id: 4,
  user_id: 1,
  stock_id: 2,
  created_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 01:04:06 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 01:04:06 UTC +00:00>]
```

Am I implementing `include?` incorrectly?  Have I messed up something in my models?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is a datatype comparison problem. Try this:

```
   def following_stock?(stock)
     # either use this
     stock_relationships.where(stock_id: stock.id).present?
     # OR
     stock_relationships.pluck(:stock_id).include?(stock.id)
   end
```

Comment: So, both answers work, including John's below.  Which one is more efficient on the DB?

Comment: `stock_relationships.where(stock_id: stock.id).present?` provided you've indexed your `stock_id` column.

Comment: @oreoluwa If you're only testing for existence, `.exists?` is even better. ;)

Comment: the other becomes a bottleneck when a user is following many stocks

Comment: true @coreyward. but I think this approach caches it, in case the OP wants to loop through the records. exists? doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I am not at a computer in which i can test at this very moment, however looking at your code, I get a sneaky suspicion the cause may be the `source` declaration in your has_many through relation.

In your User model you have `source: :user` which i believe is making the relation look for the `user_id` and not the `stock_id` when searching from the `User` side of the relation.

You may want to change it to `source: :stock`, or in your case as the model name and relation are the same, it might be okay for you to leave out the `source` decleration completely.

Comment: Got rid of `source: :user` altogether, still returning false though, even after I follow another stock with `user.follow_stock(stock)`.

Comment: I think i may have just found the other problem, in your following stock method you are calling `.include?` on the collection but passing only an id, I think you need to either pass the whole object as a parameter, or call the include on an array of ids, so perhaps change it to: `stock_relationships.map(&:stock_id).include?(stock.id)`

Comment: feel free to accept oreoluwas answer if it is more efficient, I am not in a position to test which is at the moment and don't have the knowledge off the top of my head, am just here to help so if you get it working thats all great! Although I will just add to be sure that you take care of that `source` issue to beause that may come back to bite you at some point in the future! :)